# primefaces fileUpload miniatures

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces

I want to upload multiple files but after I execute upload the miniature dissapears and I don't know which files I uploaded. Is there a way to keep miniatures with names after uploading?

Comment: Not exactly how you wanted, but you can handle the file names & the number of files in the backing bean, and then display those info in the view using outputText or <p:growl> or <p:messages>, similar to the approach used in [multiple fileupload](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/fileUploadMultiple.jsf) in Primefaces Showcase

Comment: primefaces does not handle this automatically. you'll have to do it by yourself. if only the file names are enough for you then it's easy. you can have a list of strings with the names of the uploaded files in the bean, and display it using p:dataList or ui:repeat on the page. if you also want to show miniatures it's more complex. I've managed a way of doing it, but it's not nice..

Comment: What do you mean by miniature? is the same with preview if the selected file? sorry I not really good in English.

Comment: @blitzen12: once you select files, there are small thumbnails of the images you've selected. I think he wants to keep those thumbnails too.

Answer (score 1):

I think I already done this but I'm not sure if that's what you mean.
anyway.. I use `<ui:repeat>` to show the images selected.

below is the snippit of the code:

```
 <p:outputPanel id="imagePreview">
    <ui:repeat value="#{clientController.images}" var="uploadedImages">
         <p:graphicImage value="#{controller.imageSelected}" height="135" width="135" styleClass="images"/>
    </ui:repeat>
</p:outputPanel>
```

and in your `<p:fileUpload>`.

```
<p:fileUpload id="clientProfile" immediate="true" auto="true" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" fileUploadListener="#{controller.uploadListener}" mode="advanced" multiple="true" update="imagePreview"/>
```